# Can I move snack bar of background activity to a current foreground dialog activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-snackbar

1. I have an activity running on my phone and on its button click I open a new activity but in dialog form (activity theme dialog).
2. As a error comes in my background activity I show it by **snackbar**. I can see it easily as my dialog activity is not on foreground yet.
3. But when my dialog activity is in foreground and error comes, I can't see snackbar properly as it get hide by dialog activity.
4. So i want to change the layout of **Snackbar** dynamically or any other work around will help to see my error Snack-bar in foreground.
5. Here is the code --

final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(m_androidChartLayout,error.toString(),Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

```
    snackBar.show();
```

m_androidchartLayout is the layout of Activity in background.

Comment: please add more details and code also.

Comment: Consider Activity "A" is running. and i receive any error of background task, to show that error I used snackbar on activity "A".snackbar using layout of activity "A".....Now i launched new activity "B" from activity "A", but "B" is a dialog activity. So i can see both the activity. A in background and B in foreground. ...But now the scene is i received an error and i shown it. but as snackbar is on layout of activity A. it gets hidden by B.